# How can I lock the login system in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, locking

I want to prevent all user except me to login to system in a period of time. How can I do that?

Like I login as hello.world@email.com and I have function to import data from big CSV file (about 20k record), so I want to prevent other user except hello.world@email.com to login while the data is importing.

I try to use:

- Set flag on all user as locked: This one is not good when the system grows and has a ton of users
- Add a class variable to `ApplicationController` like `@@system_lock_only_for` and keep hello.world@email.com inside and have a `before_filter` like

  ```
  if @@system_lock_only_for && @@system_lock_only_for != current_user.email
      redirect_to somewhere_path
  end
  ```

  But I'm not sure it is the best way.

How could I better solve this problem?

PS. I'm using Devise with Rails 3.2

Comment: Why do you need to lock your application?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want users to access it then you could just shut off the web server and do your import from the command line.

Alternatively you could set a global variable that you check on each request and spot out a maintainence page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

We may use session for Authentication.

Refer this link:
https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/magic_columns.rb#L65

```
def last_request_update_allowed?
  action_name != "check_session_timed_out"
end
```

use **redirect_to somewhere_path** when session is expired. That's it.